# JPA + PostgreSQL: Only time being persisted

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a PostgreSQL table containing a **`timestamp without time zone`** field. This is configured in my Java code as follows:

```
@Column(name = "timestamp")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private java.util.Date timestamp;
```

The timestamp property is being set to `new Date()` i.e. containing both the date and the time. However in the database the date part is not being persisted e.g. "14:40:28.889"; therefore when it is retrieved from the database the date is not loaded and set to default i.e. 01/01/1970. Any ideas where the date part of the timestamp is running off to?

UPDATE:
I increased the logging level for hibernate so I can see what is being persisted by adding the following in the application.properties file:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
```

The log output was as follows:

`binding parameter [6] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Wed Sep 16 08:57:03 CEST 2015]`

UPDATE 2:

I stepped through the code and found the insert sql with the date formatted as `2015-09-16 11:16:09.416000 +02:00:00`. I insert the string automatically in PGAdmin and it insert with no error. After save a clicked the little refresh button and the date part disappeared! So the data is being persisted correctly but somehow postgre is doing something weird afterwards.

Comment: look at the SQL used to persist it?

Comment: Since it uses JPA I only call the save() method and the logs only show `insert into batch_steps (item_id, result, step, step_id, success, timestamp) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

Comment: most (all) JPA providers have options to see the parameters passed in. You don't say which one you use. JPA has no "save" method

Comment: I use the save method provided by `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository`

Comment: So you're using "Spring Data JPA" NOT the JPA API. As said though, all JPA providers (DataNucleus, EclipseLink, Hibernate etc) provide a way of seeing what values those parameters have, so consult the docs of whatever you're using.

Comment: What data-type does your corresponding postgres column have?

Comment: Updated the question with log output as suggested by @NeilStockton .

Comment: @BhashitParikh The table column is set to timestamp without time zone

Comment: Wow, I don't even have a decent hypotheses. Well, can you turn on postgres query logging and see if the data loss occurs at the app level or the db level. If you find that the loss occurs on the db side, maybe there are some triggers? If on the app side, well, probably try setting breakpoints in the hibernate code, and follow the trail to see where it leads (maybe something like @PrePersist or hibernate interceptors somewhere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was one of the silliest mistakes ever, I had a script that creates the tables and it was marked as "time without timezone" i.e. not timestamp so PostgreSQL was obviously removing the date. I will leave this question as it might help someone debug similar issues.